# Add an html footer/header in php files

Tags: php, html, header, footer

I have an html website, I then have a php section of the website in wordpress for a shop page.

I want to use my current footer and header from my html pages for my php shop pages.

Any suggestions?!

Comment: To read a book and if you have a error you can come back.

Answer (score 2):

Put the  section inside the  tags of your HTML page, and you should be good to go. Make sure to rename your files from name.html to name.php, otherwise the PHP code inside cannot be used. Without specific code examples, we are not able to help you much more then this: If you can, update your question with code examples and what you've tried already, so we are more likely to be able to help you.

Code example

```
<html>
    <body>
        <!-- Normal content goes in here -->

        <?php
            // Your PHP code goes in here
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```